# Why does baseline have RL vehicles in the enviornment?

Tags: flow-project

In merge012.py, the baseline performance of the merge scenario should not include any RL control.
I am confused, however, because the VehicleParams includes vehicles with an RLController for an acceleration_controller. How can I be sure no RL is used ?
[merge0.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHczz.png)

Answer (score 0):

we're migrating questions away from stackoverflow to help us be more responsive. Please join our slack channel at https://join.slack.com/t/flow-users/shared_invite/enQtNzk5NzE1OTkyNTE0LTU0YmE5ZTVkZmJmNDg1Nzg2YThjOThmY2ZlYWE2ZjQ0NTE1NjE3Y2YwMTljY2U5M2Y3MDhmMWUzZDM3YWViNmE

But, to answer your question, merge0.py is not the baseline case. The correct script is merge012.py in flow/benchmarks/baselines